# TortoiseSVN is giving me a Tree Conflict

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tree, conflict

I had branched from trunk a few weeks ago.  I made some changes on the branch, including moving some directories.  Committed the directory move changes then merged them back to the trunk (the other changes remained on the branch for a future revision).

Now, I want to merge the trunk changes to the branch to continue development of the future revision.  I had tagged the repository pre and post merge and logged that I made a merge when I committed the initial merge to trunk.  I used the merged revision # as my From revision and the latest rev (also happens to be HEAD right now) as the To rev.

The merge today was filled with conflicts, including tree conflicts on the directories that were previously moved and merged successfully.  This is a problem since there are changes and new additions within the relocated dirs (nothing to do with the old locations).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: To keep your branch updated with all the changes from trunk you can omit the *From* and *To* revision numbers. At least if your version of svn supports merge tracking (introduced in 1.5).

Comment: Also when you say that you merged changes back to trunk did you do a *reintegrate* merge. After such a merge the branch shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: I ended up taking the easy route.  Since I had neglected to merge the trunk changes prior to merging the branch changes back to the trunk, I figured it would be simpler to just make a new branch and merge in the outstanding changes from the other branch.  I still had a few conflicts (seems the merge code is still a bit wonky - was making conflicts out of some very obvious changes) but they were easily sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is SVN knows about merging only in one way, only tree that you commit after merge knows that it was merge (in 1.5+).
In my opinion You have conflicts because SVN try to make changes to branch that are from branch and was merged to trunk. 
Try first to merge commit(s) to trunk that are merged from branch with --record-only.
record-only does only cahnge merge-info property. After that merge (and commit to branch) You should be able to merge another commits from trunk.